# Show div on hover issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this fiddle you will fill when i hover on "action" a dropdown is showed.

The problem is when we see the last item it goes below the scroll and it is not seen.
in `.scrollable` class i have used the `position:relative;`

```
.scrollable
{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 300px;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;    
}
```

and the child class "drop" has the `position:absolute;`

i dont want to change the `position:relative` of `.scrollable` class and i want the `.drop` element to  comeout of the scrollable on hover and `.drop` should not be shown below the scroll;

here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/napper7/XPxsx/15/
THanks in advance!!

Comment: Your problem cannot be solved with pure CSS. You need to use JavaScript to achieve your desired result.

Comment: can you help me with that..use fiddle..

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you could do that when using the psuedo `last-child`?

Comment: If you were able to change the display of `.scrollable` to `static` then you can change the `.drops` display to `absolute` and it will take care of the problem.  So long as there is no ancestor to the `.drops` within `scrollable` with `position:relative` or similar which will contain `absolute` elements, they will effectively break out of that container.  Since you don't want to change this, you cannot use CSS alone unless you use a very confusing DOM.

Comment: As jonBreizh maintioned, elements can't break out of the element which has `overflow` set. However, there's a trick, please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NGLD2/ . It's probably not exactly what you need, but maybe it's useful base to develope on.

Answer (score 3):

here is a working code,i added a bit of js to get the current cursor position

```
$('.navItem').each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function(e) {
       $(this).find(".drops").css('left',e.pageX-20);   
       $(this).find(".drops").css('top',e.pageY);            

    }, function(e) {});
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XPxsx/43/

Answer (score 0):

```
    .scrollable
{      
    position:relative;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;    
}​
```

I think your best bet is to drop off the overflow behavior. As far as I know, it is not possible to display nested divs outside their parent when it has an overflow value different from visible. Ever other values clip the outside box content of some sort (either by adding a scrollbar or by hiding completely the content)

I edited a jsfiddle that does what you want but without a scrollbar :
http://jsfiddle.net/XPxsx/42/

And here is some documentation on overflow behavior :
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html

Anything out of this, will be using js to display the content in a different place DOM wise.

Also, as a more general opinion : it is good to use sass (i guess from css indentation),  but even better to order your selectors in a meaning order, that would be from the most general to the most specific (such as html, then body, then div.. in your case .scrollable, then .actionTools, then .navItem..)

hope that helps